# Solr around search: Get position of a specific result, and the results around it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

I'm not sure, if Solr can handle such a thing, or if there are other workarounds:

I have a search in solr, with several parameters, in a Rails app. The results are displayed, paginated, on a website. When a user clicks on a result, I want to present them other results before and after the clicked result on the detail page, so that she or he can click through the list on the detail page of a result.

How can I do such a thing? For now, I'm caching the search parameters in a session, repeat the search, get all hits back, and search in the array for the position of my current element. The drawback is obvious: This becomes slower and slower, the more results the whole search returns (in my case about 2.8s for a search with 5000 results).

So, is there some "around-search" feature in Solr, that I don't know? Like, I have the search parameters, and the ID of a product, and want to display the results around a specific result?

I know that I could cache all the results BEFORE the detail page, but that would mess up with pagination.

I hope I made myself clear, otherwise, please comment ;)

Comment: "I want to present them other results before and after the clicked result on the detail page, so that she or he can click through the list on the detail page of a result" - How many results before and after the selected result needs to be displayed ? Is it just 1 result either side or can the results be paginated again on the detailed page ? something like a scroll pane where products are displayed

Comment: It's about 3-4 result on each side. Maybe a pagination will come later. Do you have an idea how to do this, with a better performance?

Comment: Just thinking on top of my head , see if it helps , when you do a search , you would obviously be fetching items in a paginated order in the search results page eg : pg - 1 ( 1 - 10 ) , pg -2 ( 11 - 20 ) etc ... so , when the user clicks on a particular result , along with sending the productId , send the sequence order number on that page and the page number to the backend. So if he is clicking on the 7th item in the second page , then send seq no - 7 , pg no - 2 , and on the server fetch items (2 - 1)+7 - (3 or 4) to (2 -1)+7 + (3 or 4 ).

Comment: I hope you are not fetching all the 5000 results every time , I have close to 100000 records , but it hardly takes more than a second to retrieve the results